# Using react.useEffect and mobx.autorun together

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx-react

In the MobX with React docs, in the  [Side effects and observables](https://mobx-react.netlify.com/recipes-effects) section there is a receipe to respond to changes inside a `useEffect` hook.

```
import React from 'react'
import { autorun } from 'mobx'

function useDocumentTitle(store: TStore) {
  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      autorun(() => {
        document.title = `${store.title} - ${store.sectionName}`
      }),
    [], // note empty dependencies
  )
}
```

The example combines `React.useEffect` with `mobx.autorun` (but it could be `mobx.reaction`), but I can not see the benefit of `autorun` in the code. Once we are inside `useEffect` we can track our dependencies in the dependency array. The code is more clear, there is no need to `dispose()` and `useEffect` has a clear dependency array with what is needed.

```
import React from 'react'
import { autorun } from 'mobx'

function useDocumentTitle(store: TStore) {
  React.useEffect(() => document.title = `${store.title} - ${store.sectionName}`
  ,[store.title, store.sectionName])
}
```

**Is there any reason to follow the example as given?**

Here is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-with-hooks-e7m00)

Comment: Have you checked if the version without autorun works?

Comment: Yes, I have included a code sandbox link in the post.

Comment: Not a best case to test this on. From what I see it will redraw anyway, 'cause parent is updating too.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I have updated the example to avoid a parent reload on store change and find a difference between the two approaches. Using `autorun` inside `useEffect` the side effect is executed with no reload of the component while using the `useEffect` only approach runs a reload of the component on every update.

Answer (score 6):

`autorun` creates an observer, which means it will watch for any changes in `store.title` and `store.sectionName`, and *automatically run* whenever they change.

Setting it up in `useEffect` ensures that the `autorun` observer is only created once, and removed when the component is unmounted. Note that `useEffect` doesn't actually run when the store value changes; its effect is that `autorun` is (un)registered when the component (un)mounts.

Your second example without `autorun` would still run the effect and thus update the title if this component is re-rendered by other means, either because a parent component triggers a re-render, or **if this component is wrapped in an observer**, as in the Sandbox example:

```js
function Test(props) {
  // 2. rerendered by observer when the value changes

  useEffect(() => {
    // <-- 3. execute effect because (2) rendered with a different dependency
  }, [props.store.size]); // <-- 1. observer notes this value is accessed

  return ( ... );
}

// <-- 1. observe any store value that is accessed in the Test function
export default observer(Test);
```

(edited for clarification)

Comment: `store.title` and `store.sectionName` should be observed by just including them in the `useEffect` dependency array, there is no need that a parent observes them. I do not clear understand your point.

Comment: @DavidCasillas I believe you already answered your own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306057/using-react-useeffect-and-mobx-autorun-together/65123050#comment103026373_58306057. tl;dr When title/sectionName changes in the store, `useEffect` doesn't trigger a rerender. `autorun` does. For the `useEffect` to run, something else would have to cause a rerender.

Comment: Both aproaches work, and there is no parent observing the value.  I interpret from your comment that the second approach does only work if a parent is observing the value, so is best to use the first, but this is not what I see. The only benefit I can tell is that `autorun` executes without the need to reload the component where it is defined, while with no autorun the whole component is reloaded to run the `useEffect`. If you inspect the logs the autorun example only logs inside the `autorun`, while the other logs inside the `useEffect`and in the component body.

Comment: If you're referring to the Sandbox example, the reason `useEffect` is called in the `Test` component is because the Test component is observed with `export default observer(Test);`. That means that mobx observes changes to the value of store.size in the `Test` function, causing a rerender of the Test component.

On the contrary, although `TestAutorun` is also wrapped in an `observer`, the function itself doesn't access the store.size property directly, therefore the component doesn't rerender on change. However, the store.size value is accessed in autorun, which reruns on its own.