# MobX + React. Can someone show some real useful cases for autorun, intercepter and observe?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm using MobX + React in my project near half of year. We use only @observer, @computed, reaction and sometimes when

Can someone show really useful cases for using autorun, intercepter and observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autorun`

Since you are using react (or any other framework that has mobx bindings) there is no real case to use `autorun`. When you are using `reactjs` you are wrapping your components in `observer` so they are automatically wired to respond (`render`) to mobx observables.
But if you are using vanilla js, then `autorun` is essential because it enables you to react to mobx changes. If you look at the documentation for [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) you will see that all the examples are vanilla js.

`observe`

It is a powerful low-level function that enables you to monitor what is actually happening to your `observables`. So let's say in case of an `Array` you can *observe* the changes that are happening to the array, so you can be notified exactly what has been changed. For example, you can be notified what value *exactly was added*, at what *index*. You can't do that with regular arrays, but since mobx is wrapping everything with proxies you might say that this function sits between the proxy and the *real* array and monitors how proxy (mobx) is modifying the array. More info in the [docs - observe](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#observe)

`intercept`

It is a function similar to the `observe` you might think of that function that sits **above** the `observe` function and it has a chance to change the values that mobx is trying to assign to the observables. So in case that you have `person.job` object and property you can set up `intercept` on `person.job` and you will have the chance to modify the value that should be assigned to the `person.job` and before mobx notifies everyone of that change. So in the case of `person.job` you can force only `pilot` or `sailor` values, and throw on anything else. More info in the [docs - intercept](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#intercept)

Comment: One usage pattern for `autorun` that has emerged is to get a `useEffect` hook to respond to changes in observable objects. Depending on the observable being tracked, placing it in the hook's dependency array will not trigger an update. As I understand, within the dependency array, since the mobx observable's reference does not change, it means we need to return an autorun from within the hook to maintain reactivity within the component. The mobx docs reference this pattern and you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58306057/609021)